# MYSQL Avg the last 100 values not sorted correctly. Sort before avging

Tags: mysql

I have written a SQL query to find the average number of hours between 2 date and times

```
SELECT  labtestdate, ROUND(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(concat(labtestdate, ' ', labtesttime),arrivedatlabdatetime))/ 3600), 0 ) AS timediff
FROM    results WHERE labtestdate IS NOT NULL AND labtesttime IS NOT NULL and testresult IS NOT NULL and arrivedatlabdatetime IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY sampleref
ORDER BY labtestdate DESC
LIMIT 100
```

This works brilliantly giving me 100 rows giving me an average of 14 hours of each of the last 100 (some more, some less) however if I don't group by sampleref i don't get a value and instead get only one row (which is what I want) but with a really old test date, like it's getting 100 rows then ordering them?

I also get a lot of instances of
Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect time value: '-2689:43:01'

what am I missing here? How can I tweak this so that it gives me the avg hours between `arrivedatlabdatetime` and `labtestdate labtesttime` for just the most recent tested samples by `labtestdate labtesttime` and where `arrivedatlabdatetime`, `labtestdate`,`labtesttime` and `testresult` is not null or empty ?

thanks

Comment: you need a subquery to select 100 rows of candidate data, and do `avg` on the subquery

Comment: okay so I initially select my 100 rows, sorted by my date with my applicable where query, then from those, select the AVG so I'm averaging just the 100 rows. Right... back to the drawing board for this one then